# How to reset screenshot permissions for an app on Ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: gnome, permissions, wayland, screenshot, 22.10

I've installed Ubuntu 22.10 and I use Upwork there.
For those who don't know - it makes screenshots while you work.
On 22.04 it asks permissions for each screenshot, however it seems in 22.10 it changed

Ubuntu asked me only once to make a screenshot, I've accidentelly chosen "No" and it seems this setting was saved somewhere - now Upwork cannot acquire a screen for the screenshot and I cannot make Ubuntu to ask once again so I can allow it.

I've tried to remove Upwork completely and reinstall it - it didn't help
I've tried to find any signs of permission settings for apps - it seems there is one for flatpack or snap apps but not regular apps.

Any hint how can I change or reset upwork permission in Ubuntu 22.10 or Gnome 43?

Note: I'm using Wayland and I'm **not** willing to move to Xorg (wayland is WAY more fluent, and in my case much more stable when I don't restart computer for a long time, plus - it's much more secure - I prefer apps having problem making screenshots vs any app can grab my screen any time with no warning)

Thanks in advance for any hints!

Comment: You may want to contact the group that is responsible for that app and ask them if it works with 22.10.

Comment: The dialog to grant screenshot permission was ubuntu one. It looks ubuntu saved somewhere a setting to not allow to make a screenshot and I want to clear or enable this permission.
I've updated the question to state that clearer.

Comment: Yes I understood your question but that does not mean that the app is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation but concerning `Flameshot`. I ended up on this forum (coincidentally Upwork) where someone posted a python script to change the permission.

Here the script to execute:

```py
import dbus
bus = dbus.SessionBus()
perm = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore', '/org/freedesktop/impl/portal/PermissionStore')
perm_iface = dbus.Interface(perm, dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore')

perm_iface.Lookup("screenshot", "screenshot")
perm_iface.Set("screenshot", dbus.Boolean(True), "screenshot", {"": ["yes"]}, dbus.Byte(0x00))
perm_iface.Lookup("screenshot", "screenshot")
```

Here the solution source: https://community.upwork.com/t5/Freelancers/Constantly-asking-for-permission-to-share-screenshot-on-Gnome/m-p/1222388#M731300